# Single transistor VCA for gate type CV signals

Tags: transistors, audio, single-supply-op-amp, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I am in the process of designing a sort of mini synth / noise machine and I'm struggling with the output stage. I only want sound to come out when I press the button, so based on some designs I have found on the internet I have come up with this. I've simulated it with Falstad and also tested it on a prototyping board and it seems to work correctly, but I'd still like to make sure it doesn't compromise any components and also ask if there is a better design out there (without having to add many more components).

[image]

The CV signal will not actually come directly from the button as shown in the schematic, it will come from a transistor used as a switch that will be activated with a 5V signal, but as far as I know this doesn't affect this particular part of the circuit.

Also, searching for information on the internet, I have only found good results searching for VCA schematics, but they are usually more complex circuits. What I am looking for is a VCA but only for gate type CV signals, is there a specific term for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try muting circuits: https://sound-au.com/articles/muting.html

Note the catch with unbalanced switches or mixers: the bias current flows into the signal path.  Your example does, in fact, (nearly) minimize this -- base current can flow out Q1 collector (inverted mode) into a low impedance sink (op-amp output), while Vce(sat) stays near zero (including for negative C-E (inverted mode)), so the error is a bit of Vce(sat), plus whatever base bias does to that*.  But this isn't always possible in general, and when it's not, it leads to the offset being dumped into the output -- yes, it's filtered for DC blocking, but it takes time to get down to "DC", and until then you have a big fat start/stop transient, or the wobble as it varies (for the VCA case).

*It could be improved further, actually, by taking the first op-amp's feedback from after Q1 -- this way the amp has no control authority over its feedback node, when off (Q1 high impedance -- will need Vebo > Vcc, mind), so its output goes saturated (Vcc/Vee) in a futile effort to convince the output to move; when on, it takes a little time for the amp to come out of saturation (which will still deposit some charge in the output, a quiet pop -- a transconductance amp like LM13700 may be more attractive here as its output can be safely shorted to GND), but thereafter operates as normal, indeed compensating for the slightly asymmetrical Vce(sat) in the process (so on-state distortion is minimal).

Another tweak is to apply balanced base bias, i.e. pushing current into the base and pulling an equal amount out the emitter or collector.  This doesn't do anything to Vce(sat) asymmetry, but removes the bias error.  As I understand, this was used in early DACs, before CMOS switches were introduced (the 1960s were a rough time in digital electronics!).

You could go further and use an 'L' or 'T' style switch (see examples linked above; Fig. 5 shows an 'L' type, notice LDR1 is in series with the input, LDR2 shunting the output; 'T' is this with another switch in series with the output) to get higher isolation, and buffer the output (i.e. a voltage follower from the left side of your R3), and then use a series resistor and some clamping diodes to reduce the first amp's saturation (a common trick e.g. used in precision rectifier circuits).  But this is starting to get rather complicated, and you'll start to feel really happy that analog switch ICs exist for you. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive response and for sharing the link to the muting circuits, I was not aware of their existence! I have tried changing the feedback loop as you indicated, but I haven't seen much difference. I have measured with my oscilloscope and in both cases I get almost symmetrical voltages of around +/-20mV for Vce(sat). Maybe I'm measuring wrong, I don't have much experience with oscilloscopes. As for applying balanced base bias, do you mean using 4.5V instead of 9V at the base of the transistor?

Comment: Also, regarding the resistor values, I understand that all I have to make sure is that R5 is small enough for the transistor to be in saturation. Would it be convenient to increase the value of R3 to minimize the amount of current? (changing of course the values of R4 and C2 to keep the gain and cutoff frequency of the last stage)

Comment: @JavierSoto Balanced as in currents -- actually, like the diode switch on the link, Fig.6, but instead of shunting signal to GND, the pull-up / pull-down transistors just apply currents to a switching BJT, into base and out of emitter, while C-E is the switch terminals.  As for resistors, the values you have are probably fine; inverted hFE is pretty low for most types, so maybe R5 could be a bit smaller. Also see if you can get a low-Vce(sat) or "muting" type transistor.

Comment: To explain that last bit: most low-Vce(sat) types have surprisingly good inverted hFE -- a consequence of getting low Vce(sat) in the forward direction, is having it low in reverse as well. Some are indeed rated with "Rce(on)", in analogy to FETs. Families include Diodes' ZTXxxx, Nexperia's PBSSxxx, various Panasonic parts I don't recall offhand, etc.